# Installing Linux and windows on dual boot - specific problm

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, multi-boot, bootloader

I already have Linux installed on my laptop, Kali Linux 2.0 (latest) to be specific.

Due to some software requirements for programming I have to install windows 10 also on my laptop as dual boot.

I have done this several times before but usually I install windows first and then Linux which is an easier way.

This time it's opposite and I really need some guidance.

I can try to shrink my Linux volume first and try to install windows on the free space and reconfigure the bootloader, that,s the plan but the question is will it work?

Will windows allow that?

Can I reconfigure the bootloader easily?

Is there any other way? I really need answer to this or I'll have to wipe my disk to install both of them again.

Comment: Could you install VirtualBox on kali and then install Windows 10 as a guest VM? This will save some worry...

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to:

1. Shrink linux volume
2. Install Windows 10 in the free space
3. Install EasyBCD in Windows, and use it to add Kali Linux to the Windows bootloader

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could do that.

If you wanted to use a shrunk partition though, through out the Windows 10 installer make sure to 'expand space' on the Linux partion, and make a drive out of the space.

Use a bootloader program (I highly suggest EasyBCD) if either the Linux partiton or Windows partiton is not coming up in a bootloader (GRUB or Windows). When installing Ubuntu, for me I could see both in the bootloader.

Hope this helps!